# Почему KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED не обрабатывает нажатие клавиши «ENTER»?

Tags: java, javafx

Создаю графическое приложение на JavaFX. Задача состоит в том, что бы при нажатии клавишей клавиатуры визуально отображалось нажатие кнопки ей соответствующей, путем

```
buttonA.arm();
buttonA.disarm();
```

На сцену вешаю слушатели событий

```
stage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, this::keyDown); 
stage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, this::keyUp);
```

Но почему то KeyEvent.**KEY_PRESSED** не отлавливает нажатие клавиши **ENTER**. Но отлавливает, если клавиша ENTER нажата вместе с *SHIFT* или *CTRL*. (KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED работает нормально)

В чем причина данной нелогичной ситуации?

Update: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8116061

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данную проблему помог решить **EventFilter**

Теперь же событие KEY_PRESSED клавиши ENTER перехватывается:

```
Main.stage.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, this::keyDown);
```

**EventFilter** позволяет перехватить события во время фазы захвата, до обработки дочерними узлами. Так как клавиша ENTER выполняет системные функции, ее быстро перехватывают UI элементы, и stage не успевает его обработать через EventHandler, по этому данная проблема и появляется